# Want to get meta_title ( Page Title in category )

Tags: magento-1.9, category, meta

I want to add to get page title in title tag (of head ) 
i tried

```
<?php if ($_category->getMetaTitle()):?>
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getMetaTitle(), 'meta_title') ?>
<?php else: ?
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

simply add this in your head

```
if(Mage::registry('current_category'))
{
   echo  Mage::registry('current_category')->getMetaTitle();
}else {

 echo $this->getTitle()
 }
```

Comment: Buy adding this code homepage title disn't display

Comment: @Payaljhamta added the code for that

Comment: used this working<?php if(Mage::registry('current_category'))
{
   echo  Mage::registry('current_category')->getMetaTitle();
}
else  {
   echo $this->getTitle() ;
 } ?>

Answer (score 0):

Magento, default  take **page  title** from page title from `meta_title`

You can see  that [Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php#L44) , and you will understand that `it taking from  meta_title field`,if that field  have  value for that **particular category** .

May be

- your system have any extensions
- Or customization
- As you have **multiple store_view/store** then you did not set vale
  for your **particular store**s

You need to fix those. then it will  work properly